# Is there a library-less implementation of DSA available to read?

Tags: implementation, dsa

Is there a pedagogical library-less implementation of DSA available to read?  (Not ECDSA.)

Obviously BigInteger and hash functions may be from libraries, but I want to *read* the implementation of all of the calculations involved in signing a message and verifying a signature, using whatever BigInteger operations are appropriate for the language.

Ideally it will treat keys as numbers, and not interact with DER/PEM file formats in any way.

Java, Python, Javascript, Haskell, or even C would be great.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Not great answers but something:

If you just want the mathematical computations, indepedent of implementation, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) has a good explanation, and [the standard](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) is definitive.

**Java JCE** source is open. The repository is git (which I don't have set up); Oracle(Sun) JDK distribution has src.zip but exclude the JCE part; JRE distribution has no source at all. openjdk-src package for CentOS/RedHat does include JCE, and I'd assume/expect at least some other Unixes but maybe not Windows the same. The JCE facade/provider/engine framework somewhat complicates the code for all providers, including DSA.

**Java BouncyCastle** (http://www.bouncycastle.org) source is open. Their build recipe is too complicated for me, but can be avoided by downloading the jar(s) and the source and telling your debugger to link them; I use Eclipse and just set the source property for the library. BC includes both a provider implementation, with the same complication as the Oracle one, but also a "lightweight" API, where you just call an implementation directly; `org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.DSASigner` is the one you want here. That's what I'd use if I wanted to debug something in Java.

**OpenSSL C** (http://www.openssl.org) source is open. Beyond a standard C toolchain (compiler, preprocessor if separate, assembler if separate, linker, lib/archive, etc, and debugger) build requires only perl (builtin to nearly all Unix, and easily available for Windows); a separate assembler can be needed for an optimized build, but for pedagogical you don't need optimized. Although linked enough you need to *build* the whole thing, for execution the code is quite well modularized and you can easily write a small program that just calls the `DSA_*` and `BN_*` (bignum) modules to do a few DSA operations. However, C code must explicitly deal with error handling and memory management that is (mostly) implicit in Java, and OpenSSL C code for older modules is not exactly the clearest possible. OpenSSL also makes it easy to add file handling when and only when you want.

Note that the numbers involved in DSA, even using the long-obsolete 512-bit minimum of original FIPS186, will be much too large to deal with or check or recognize manually, so you can step through code and see that it does something that works, but won't actually learn any more about what it does than the formulas in the spec told you to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Is it sensible to implement DSA with tiny key lengths (8-16 bit?) to get a feel for how it works, or will confusing problems occur at that size.  (I realize that a 16 bit key can be cracked by a man with an abacus in 3,4 seconds).

Comment: The formulas still work, and I'd expect "bignum" arithmetic does. No lib I know of, certainly not JCE or OpenSSL, will generate parameters and key(s) less than 512-bits so you'd have to do that by hand; there is no standard for p-size vs q-size but you could arbitrarily choose say q 8bits and p 16bits. The APIs I describe are after the hash so hashsize isn't an issue. But for such small numbers you could just use a desk calculator or even do the arithmetic by hand, you don't really need a computer. A toy example like that wouldn't help me, but people are different and maybe it helps you.